# SSRS KeepWithGroup Property

Tags: reporting-services, static

Scenario: I have my SSRS report laid out like this:

```
 Static Row Group       (KeepWithGroup = After)   <--  Static Rowgroup is associated to RowGroup1

  RowGroup1
      subRowGroup1
        subRowGroup2   
  RowGroup2
```

My report is structured in such a way where the Static Row Group which is a header is associated to rowgroup1. So after each iteration of RowGroup1 my headers displays.  RowGroup2 serves as a totals page
for the sum of my RowGroup1.  Is there a way to Call the Static rowgroup after BOTH RowGroups? The only option i have at the moment is to insert those rows as a copy above RowGroup2 Since it occurs only once, but I've been tasked with seeing if I can reuse the same static group. Any help would be appreciate thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS doesn't have a built-in feature for this exact scenario. In other words, you would need to make a copy of the `Static Row Group` to make it show up again by `RowGroup2`.

If the concern had to do with limiting the complexity of the report, you may consider moving the calculations to be fields in the dataset. Then both static rows can reference those same fields and the expressions are maintained all in one place.

Comment: Thank you @StevenWhite, unforatunately this report is riddled with expressions and is past restructuring. I went ahead with the insert. Thanks for the feedback!